# Odd issues with int and NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsinteger

Have spent several hours on this and am sure I'm missing something completely obvious. I'm new to cocoa/objective c and rusty with pointers / objects, and thus would greatly appreciate someone (kindly!) pointing out where I'm going wrong.

Here is my code:

`.h` file:

```
@property (assign) NSInteger *freeTrialCounter;
```

`.m` file

```
NSInteger a = 2;
self.freeTrialCounter = &(a);   

NSLog(@"Free Trial Counter: %d", *self.freeTrialCounter);

int b = *self.freeTrialCounter;
NSLog(@"B: %d", b);
```

here is the output:
**Free Trial Counter: 2** **B: 1606411536**

What am I missing here? Why isn't "B" equal to "2"?

Comment: What's the point of creating a pointer to an `int` as a property? Merely for experimental purposes or what? This is not something that seems to have any common real-world application

Comment: Tried your code, B returns 2 for me.
Only possible issue I thought of, is that NSInteger is actually a long and not an int. Meaning it is 64bit and not 32bit. You have possible data loss when doing the explicit conversion with 'b'

Comment: dandan78 & Yameo: see my response below to Caleb's help... was following the advice of XCode "&(a)" and it led me astray. (Being new to this language, I assumed I ought to listen to the IDE's advice... I know better now!) Thanks for your time and assistance on this.

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem is that `int` and `NSInteger` can be different sizes. So, you're assigning a pointer to an `NSInteger` to a property of type `NSInteger*`, which is okay (but unusual). However, you're dereferencing that value as an `int`, which happens not to be the same size.

However, I think that you may also be confused about how you need to declare a property to hold an `NSInteger`. `NSInteger` is just a simple integer type, not an object, so there's no need to use a pointer to refer to it. This is doubly true since you seem to be declaring the `NSInteger` whose address you're taking on the stack, so the pointer will be invalid as soon as the method where you do the assignment ends.

You'll be much better off using a plain old `NSInteger` property and not trying to use a pointer here. Do this instead:

```
@property (assign) NSInteger freeTrialCounter;
//...
NSInteger a = 2;
self.freeTrialCounter = a;   

NSLog(@"Free Trial Counter: %ld", self.freeTrialCounter);

NSInteger b = self.freeTrialCounter;
NSLog(@"B: %ld", b);
```

Note that I've also changed the type of `b` to `NSInteger` to match the property type. Since they're not necessarily the same size, mixing the two can (as you've seen) cause problems. Likewise, I've changed the format specifier from `%d` to `%ld` to match the 64-bit size of `NSInteger`.

Comment: If he wanted to use pointers, for whatever reason, thats his choice. You aren't really helping him find his problem. Rather just giving an alternative.

Comment: @Yarneo You make a fair point and I'll edit to address the actual problem. OTOH, there's really not much point to storing a pointer to an integer as a property, though, so I tend to think that the OP simply made a mistake. You *must* use pointers for objects, but `NSInteger` isn't an object type.

Comment: Thanks for the help Caleb, et. al... When I code the self.freeTrialCounter=a; XCode gives me the following "yellow warning": "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') from 'NSInteger' (aka 'long'); take the address with &" and recommends the change &(a). Being new to cocoa, I simply assumed that XCode knew what it was doing, and accepted the change... which is obviously not always accurate! Thanks very much for your help. Working brilliantly now!